# Append Dictionary<String, Any> to an Array throws exception

Tags: ios7, swift, ios8, xcode6

When trying to save a `Dictionary<String, Any>` into a `Array <Dictionary<String, Any>>`
system throws an exception `EXC_BREAKPOINT`. The same code but instead of `Any`I used `String` was working fine: `Dictionary<String, String >` stored in an `Array <Dictionary<String, String >>`

Why this happens ? I suppose it has problems with `Any` type, however I can't solve this issue, because I need that `Dictionary` to store different kind of objects

**Update**
If I declare array `var mListItems = Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>();`
as a class property then it crashes, if mListItems is declared as local variable it WORKS

Comment: Show your code, please. [This](http://pastebin.com/ULDsdSr4) works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in Swift. I can't reproduce it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Seems there are ways to fix crash:

#### A - Use AnyObject instead of Any as dictionary value type

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var mListItems = Array<Any>() // Or Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var characters = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
        characters["a"] = "A"
        mListItems.append(characters)
    }

}
```

#### B - Use NSDictionary

```
var animals = NSMutableDictionary()
animals.setValue("Miao", forKey: "cat")
mListItems.append(animals) // mListItems is Array of Any
```

Comment: this works in playground but not in my viewcontroller